# Select column from DataFrame rows using a list of column labels

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a list of values with the column index I want for each row of a pandas DataFrame.  How do I map this list of column labels to each row of the DataFrame?

If  I simply index the DataFrame using the list, the entire list gets applied to every row, like this.

```py
In [10]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5,2), columns=list('AB'))

In [11]: df
Out[11]: 
          A         B
0 -0.082240 -2.182937
1  0.380396  0.084844
2  0.432390  1.519970
3 -0.493662  0.600178
4  0.274230  0.132885

In[12]: selection = list('ABBAA')

In[13]: selection
Out[13]: ['A', 'B', 'B', 'A', 'A']

In[14]: df[selection]
Out[14]:
          A         B         B         A         A
0 -0.082240 -2.182937 -2.182937 -0.082240 -0.082240
1  0.380396  0.084844  0.084844  0.380396  0.380396  
2  0.432390  1.519970  1.519970  0.432390  0.432390
3 -0.493662  0.600178  0.600178 -0.493662 -0.493662
4  0.274230  0.132885  0.132885  0.274230  0.274230
```

Each element in the selection list indicates the column to select from the corresponding row in the DataFrame.  In this example, I want column `A` from the first row, `B` from the second and third, then `A` from the fourth and fifth.  It works out that this is the diagonal of the above result.  My actual DataFrame is much larger and I don't think it makes sense to build the above result just to select out the diagonal.

I can certainly get at this by looping over the rows but I expect Pandas has a built-in way to do this.  I am looking for the method to get the following result.

```py
In[15]: df <do something> selection
Out[15]:
0 -0.082240
1  0.084844
2  1.519970
3 -0.493662
4  0.274230
```

Comment: Do you need only the diagonal values of a selection?

Comment: yes, each element of the `selection` list indicates which column I want from different row.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are slicing the dataframe twice if you first select columns based on selection and then get the diagonal values. You can instead use [lookup](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.lookup.html) which  returns an array of the values corresponding to each (row, col) pair.

```
df.lookup(df.index, selection)

array([-0.08224 ,  0.084844,  1.51997 , -0.493662,  0.27423 ])
```

If you want the data in form of Pandas series,

```
pd.Series(df.lookup(df.index, selection))

0   -0.082240
1    0.084844
2    1.519970
3   -0.493662
4    0.274230
```

Comment: As is, this only works if the DataFrame indices match `np.arange(len(selection))`.  It would be better to simply use `df.index` as the first input to `df.lookup()`.

Comment: @StevenC.Howell, I agree. I assumed the index to be the default pandas index starting from 0

Comment: That's not genarally a safe assumption as it breaks as soon as the index is not the default.  It was for my simple example but often the index could be more descriptive.  It would be safer, and not require extra function calls, to just use `df.index`.

Comment: This would be foolproof, df.lookup(df.index[:len(selection)], selection)

Comment: Timing this answer, and @W-B's, I got the same results.  I accepted this as it uses a builtin Pandas function (which may just be calling `df.values` under the hood).

Comment: In my question I state the list has a value for every row.  I am using this to create a new column for the DataFrame. Slicing the index by the length of the selection list is not necessary.  `df.lookup(df.index, selection)` is a clean, simple, easy to understand solution.  Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Use `reindex`:

```
df.reindex(selection, axis=1)
```

Output:

```
          A         B         B         A         A
0  0.065447 -1.890299 -1.890299  0.065447  0.065447
1  0.389780  0.301049  0.301049  0.389780  0.389780
2  0.484159 -1.311432 -1.311432  0.484159  0.484159
3 -0.209745 -2.233050 -2.233050 -0.209745 -0.209745
4 -0.093495 -1.527827 -1.527827 -0.093495 -0.093495
```

Then, use `np.eye` and `mask`

```
df.reindex(selection, axis=1).mask(np.eye(5) == 0).stack()
```

Output:

```
0  A    0.065447
1  B    0.301049
2  B   -1.311432
3  A   -0.209745
4  A   -0.093495
dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 3):

I can only think of `numpy` method

```
pd.Series(df.values[df.index,df.columns.get_indexer(selection)])
Out[563]: 
0   -0.082240
1    0.084844
2    1.519970
3   -0.493662
4    0.274230
dtype: float64
```

Comment: This works just as well as the accepted answer.  Timing them on my actual DataFrame even gave the same times.

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, try this

```
df[selection].values.diagonal()
```

If, you need in the form of `Series` as you remarked, do -

```
pd.Series(df[selection].values.diagonal())
```